# Some problems with Rayleigh quotient iteration.

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Let $q_0=\frac{u_0}{||u_0||_2},\mu_0=q_{0}^{*}Aq_0,(A-\mu_{k-1}I)z_k=q_{k-1},q_k=\frac{z_k}{||z_k||_2},\mu_k=q_{k}^*Aq_k,\quad k\ge1$. Here $A\in C^{n\times n}$ and $u_0$ predetermined. If we extend $q_k$ to a unitary matrix  $Q_k = [q_k,U_k]$ and $ Q_k^*AQ_k= \begin{bmatrix} \mu_k&h_k^*\\g_k&C_k \end{bmatrix},y_k=(\mu_{k-1}I-C_{k-1})^{-1}g_{k-1},\delta_k=(1+||y_k||_2^2)^{\frac{1}{2}} $. Suppose $lim_{k\to\infty}||Aq_k-\mu_k q_k||_2=0.$The problems are as following:

(1)$q_k = \frac{1}{\delta_k}Q_{k-1}\begin{bmatrix}1\\y_k\end{bmatrix}.$
(2)When k is sufficiently large, there exists $D\in C^{(n-1)\times(n-1)}$ such that $D^*(I+y_ky_k^*)D=I, D=I+O(||g_{k-1}||_2^2$.

I've solved the first through multiplying $(A-\mu_{k-1} I)$ on both sides and just proving that the left and right are on the same line. But for the second I've no ideas, though I've found $(g_{k-1},y_k) = 1$ and tried to use rank-1 modification.

Comment: I don't know what you mean...

Comment: I meant the presentation can be improved you may write the definition$(A-\frac{z_{k-1}^*}{\|z_{k-1}\|}A \frac{z_{k-1}}{\|z_{k-1}\|})z_k=\frac{z_{k-1}}{\|z_{k-1}\|}$ with $z_0=lq_0$, $q_0$ fixed unitary $ l\in \mathbb{R}^*$, there is a question of existence that could be proven on $z_k$ also good Luck